# help me to prove Limit of f(x).

Tags: limits

I want to prove $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\bigl(1+\cfrac{k}{x}\bigr) ^x=e^k$$
I tried to use squeezing principle
But i can't able to prove the problem.

Comment: In many books this equality is a definition. What is your definition  of $e^x$?

Comment: Do you mean $x\to\infty$?

Comment: Yeah I mean $x\to\infty$

Comment: What is your definition of $e^x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering $$A=\bigl(1+\cfrac{k}{x}\bigr) ^x$$ take logarithms $$\log(A)=x\log\bigl(1+\cfrac{k}{x}\bigr)$$ Now, use that, for small $y$, $\log(1+y)\approx y-\frac {y^2}2 + O(y^3)$, replace $y$ by $\cfrac{k}{x}$. All of that makes $$\log(A)= x \times (\cfrac{k}{x}+O(\frac 1 {x^2}))=k +O(\frac 1 {x})\implies A= e^k+O(\frac 1 {x})$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{k}{x} \right)^x = \lim_{\frac{x}{k} \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac{x}{k}}\right)^{\frac{x}{k} \cdot k} = e^k$$